# textview doesn't go multiline

Tags: android, textview, android-2.3-gingerbread

Here's my XML layout example of one of my TextViews which show itself correctly in android 4.2 ... I've downgraded a Nexus S to gingerbread 2.3.6 to test out my application and debug it! Right now, each of my TextViews doesn't take any more space than one line, not even wrapping itself at the end of the first line. (On 4.2, the example below was taking 3 lines and was adding "..." at the end if there was some text missing!)

How can I make my textViews compatible with gingerbread? Thank you!

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_guideRow_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TV_guideRow_title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TV_guideRow_title"
            android:text="blabla text that could go up to 3 lines"
            android:textColor="#3BB9FF"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/TV_guideRow_more"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation, I've found out that all my related textView problems were related to my custom theme, which was made for android 4.0+ (since Holo was used as the base theme)

I've set the APIs which doesn't have holo to use the "Light" theme and everything is showing up correctly without any further modification.

Comment: I was getting crazy for 3 days for exactly the same probleme. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
```

Also, depending on the parent of that TextView, multiline may not render properly. Try manually setting the height to, say, 100dp and see if that works.